# Threshold in Image Processing with OpenCV for Android not working

Tags: android, opencv

I am working on an Android application that recognizes characters using OpenCV library for Image Processing.

I first wrote the code in Java with Eclipse and I am now transfering the code to Android Studio. The problem I am facing is that this line doesn't seem to have any effect on the Camera Preview, it shows an ordinary image with no effects.

Here are some of my declarations my declarations:

```
Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();
Size sizeRgba = rgba.size();

Mat rgbaInnerWindow;

int rows = (int) sizeRgba.height;
int cols = (int) sizeRgba.width;

int left = cols / 8;
int top = rows / 2;

int width = cols * 3 / 4;
int height = rows * 20 / 100;

rgbaInnerWindow = rgba.submat(top, top + height, left, left + width);
```

And here are the methods I applied:

```
//Filtre Gaussien
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mIntermediateMat, rgbaInnerWindow, new org.opencv.core.Size(7, 7), 0, 3);

//binarisation
Imgproc.threshold(mIntermediateMat, rgbaInnerWindow, 181, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

rgbaInnerWindow.release();
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Which function contains the code for thresholding?

Comment: This one: 
`Imgproc.threshold(mIntermediateMat, rgbaInnerWindow, 181, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);`

Comment: Sorry, rewording my question. Is the thershold function present inside the camera callback that is called every frame?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding you earlier. Yes it is called every frame inside the camera callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had to grayscale the image before processing it, so I placed `inputFrame.gray()` as the first parameter in the GaussianBlur funtion:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(inputFrame.gray(), mIntermediateMat, new org.opencv.core.Size(7, 7), 0 ,  3);
    Imgproc.threshold(mIntermediateMat, mRgba, 181, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

    return mRgba;
}
```

Also, setting up a new OpenCV project in Android Studio eliminated these errors:

> E/ LoadedApk: It takes too much time onReceive and the onReceive time
>   is:28051 ms intent is:Intent {
>   act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE_IMMEDIATE flg=0x4000010 (has
>   extras) }
>
> Skipped 38 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its
>   main thread.

Answer (score -1):

The threshold function works on a single channel image and outputs another single channel image. Since your `rgbaInnerWindow` is a 4 channel Mat that doesn't match the output dimensions, it's reference is deleted and a new matrix is created. So you don't see the result when displaying `rgba`.

Try this:

```
Imgproc.threshold(mIntermediateMat, mIntermediateMat, 181, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, rgbaInnerWindow, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA);
```

`cvtColor()`'s output will match your `rgbaInnerWindow` and `rgba` will be modified.

You can also use `Core.merge()` to replicate the single channel image on all the 4 channels and push the results to `rgbaInnerWindow`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After doing this, I am having these messages on my Logcat:

`E/ LoadedApk: It takes too much time onReceive and the onReceive time is:28051 ms intent is:Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE_IMMEDIATE flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }`
**and**
`Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

Comment: GaussianBlur is probably the culprit. Others don't take as much time. Also move any allocations that are happening in the onReceive function.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do this and I will give my feedback. But I am pretty sure that it is not the GaussianBlur because I don't have those errors when I let only the GaussianBlur function. Maybe I should process on a signle image after capturing instead of working on every frame.

Comment: If it didn't occur earlier, try using the merge method. Keeping the processing away from the UI thread helps but these are not very complicated image processing tasks, should execute fairly fast. There is something bottlenecking in your case.